# How to design a Web Service that returns cached results when called that are updated from an independent recurring thread?

Tags: c#, web-services, architecture, polling

I am looking to redesign a service that is used by several client applications.  These applications make repeated requests at 30 to 60 second intervals of one particular method on the service.  This method Gets data and then Caches it for approximately 30 to 45 seconds.  Because the method is driven by requests it checks on every request to see if the time difference from the last cache is > 30 seconds and if so refreshes it before returning the results.

While I'd eventually like to move to a pub / sub model, for now I have to stay with polling.  What I would like to do is create a repeating background process that refreshes the cache on a specified time interval independent of requests to the service.  Then as requests to the method come it would always just return from cache.

I am not sure how exactly to accomplish this?  I don't believe I want to tie the kickoff of the background thread to an initial request but I'm not sure how to start it.  Do I have to create some kind of windows service that shares an App Domain or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use cache expiration mechanism? In this case you can be sure that returned data will be correct if cached data became stale, and you don't need to do extra (possibly unneeded) requests to DB.

Comment: What triggers the initial Caching?  Is it a request to the service?  I do remember Cache has a callback on expiration that you can use.  I'm a little uncertain if there are any issues with the callback being tied that first request that triggered it.  Is it essentially holding that first session open forever?  What happens if that session is lost for some reason, is the callback broken at that point?

Comment: First caching will be triggered by request, yes. Is this a problem? How much time DB lookup takes? If it's not very long, then why you need expiration callbacks, just return data from cache if it exist or do DB lookup otherwise (and of course add new data to the cache with needed expiration). In this case you do not need to care if it's first request or not.

Comment: One of the issues we have seen with the existing is that if the query takes longer than normal to return it causes the requests to essentially back up while it waits for it to finish.  By servicing requests from cache only and updating Cache from a separate thread I hope to eliminate this.  Another advantage would be the ability actually move this processing to another machine if needed in the future.

Comment: There is simple implementation for your case. Just create another endpoint in your services that, when accessed will get the data and add it to the cache (this will work in different thread if you use IIS). Then create simple console app that will trigger this endpoint and configure it to run with task scheduler if you use Windows. You can make this endpoint to be accessible only locally. You may think of doing this endpoint more generic for other data types. Of course normal request handler should check if cache data exists, or not.